# In fullcalendar.io how to get first date time and last date time after every nav click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to call an API which accepts from_date and to_date. So every time I changed the view of the calendar I would like to call an API and update the data event accordingly. If I move forward or back how do I get the initial date and final date of the month?

[Link to full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

I have the API docs from fullcalendar.io but not sure why it is not working.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/getView

It clearly mentioned that this way you can get the view and DateTime.

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
alert("The view's title is " + view.title);
```

But when I run the above code it says

`VM39:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`

I even tried this function at the fullcalendar.io website. It says the same. Not sure what is the issue.

I am using below code to initialize my calendar.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction' , 'momentTimezone' ],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: sessionCalendar,
});
calendar.render();
```

[image: https://fullcalendar.io/]

Comment: Your code above appears to be for version 4 of fullCalendar, but the documentation link you have is for version 3. They are very different...in v4 it is no longer implemented as a jQuery plugin, which is why you get the reported error

Comment: Ohh I din't realise that. Thank you for pointing out that. But I am not even allowed to select the v4 from the dropdown any idea how can I make it work ?

Comment: But anyway, to achieve your stated requirement (i.e. _" So every time I changed the view of the calendar I would like to call an API and update the data event accordingly"_) you don't need to do this getView or anything else complicated. Just implement your event feed according to this documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: I am going to be the die-hard fan of yours :). Please post this as an answer so I mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks but I'd say it's more of a suggestion than an answer. You still have to code it yet... enjoy!